# getpcaps not working in ubuntu 20.04 with linux 5.11.0-38-generic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, capabilities

I saw on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/64000118/8507296 to check capabilities of the process using command

```bsh
getpcaps <pid>
```

### Output of ps command

```bsh
$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   9618 pts/0    00:00:02 zsh
  12797 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
  12920 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

### getpcaps

```bsh
$ getpcaps 9618
9618: =
```

### system info

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux Vostro-5568 5.11.0-38-generic 
#42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 28 20:41:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Other

but in the same answer, there is another method which is working for me, like below

```bsh
$ cat /proc/<PID>/status | grep Cap
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
$ capsh --decode=000001ffffffffff
WARNING: libcap needs an update (cap=40 should have a name).
0x000001ffffffffff=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,
cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,
cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,
cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,
cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,
cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,
cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,
cap_audit_read,38,39,40
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-zero value you are looking at in that status file is the *bounding* set (which is sort of an upper bound for actual capabilities). The bounding set is there to limit what capabilities are possible for a process. This non-zero value is the default for the system. As such, it is not an interesting value. What it is saying is that these are all the capabilities known to the running system. Its value becomes *interesting* when it changes from that default.

There is a lot of incremental history associated with the various `Cap*` entries in that status file. Only `CapInh`, `CapPrm` and `CapEff` were there in the beginning (~1999?). They were introduced to implement the POSIX.1e (draft spec, [see bottom of this page for a link to the last known copy of said draft](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/)). The `libcap` library, which provides the program `getpcaps`, was initially developed as an implementation of the user-space API for capabilities described in that spec. The text representation for *capabilities* from that spec only included these three capability *flags*.

As per the spec, the `CapInh`, `CapPrm` and `CapEff` are actual capabilities for a process, and only the `CapPrm` and `CapEff` actually give a process some direct privilege.

Later, `CapBnd` was made a per-process bounding set from which a process can only remove bits (modulo user namespace container bugs recently fixed). And after that, `CapAmb` was added. The semantics of these two vectors are that they are *naively* inheritable - a child inherits an exact copy of its parent's at the time of `exec*()`. This is very different from the semantics of `CapPrm` and `CapEff`.

When we considered these semantics and the legacy (~20 years) of a text representation, to support the A & B concepts, we created a different text representation for the 3-tuple: I, A and B: the IAB tuple. You can read about it in the [`cap_iab`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cap_iab.3.html) man page, or the documentation for [`pam_cap.so`](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/pam_cap-so). The IAB text format is what `pam_cap.so` uses for its configuration syntax. B is actually represented as the *inverse* of `CapBnd` to emphasize that the default is an uninteresting value zero. There is a longer discussion of all these mechanisms, focused on [capability inheritance here](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/inheriting-privilege).

Examples you might like to try (for purposes of comparison):

```
$ getpcaps 1
```

This one will have *a lot* of capabilities `...=ep`. You can read some more about how all the capability things work on [the `libcap` website](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/). More recent versions of `getpcaps` support an `--iab` command line option which, should it find an *interesting* (non-default IAB value) it appends the text output for a process with `[..IAB..]`. The release notes say this support was added in `libcap-2.54`.

I'm not sure what version of `libcap` you have installed, but at the time of writing `libcap-2.60` is the current version. It knows all about the unnamed capabilities you are seeing: numbered 38,39 and 40. In fact, the `libcap-2.60` version of `capsh` even supports things like:

```
$ capsh --explain=40
cap_checkpoint_restore (40) [/proc/self/status:CapXXX: 0x0000010000000000]

    Allows a process to perform checkpoint
    and restore operations. Also permits
    explicit PID control via clone3() and
    also writing to ns_last_pid.
```

Comment: but why  `getpcaps` return nothing? in my case.

Comment: I've updated the text with more details, more pointers for background and an explanation of why `getpcaps` isn't displaying the `CapBnd` value.